# Selecting text for QLinEdit by double clicking on a item in Tablewidget

Tags: python, pyqt4, selection, qlineedit

In a dialog, I have a table-widget and multiple line edits. The user clicks the mouse in one of the line-edits, and then double-clicks on an item in the table-widget. In the double-click slot (`self.myfunct`), how do I determine which line-edit had the cursor, so I can set that table-item name in the right line-edit?

```
self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('itemDoubleClicked(QTableWidgetItem *)'), self.myfunct)
```

Some wrappers are present over PyQt4 so I can't paste the code directly.

[image: screenshot1]

Comment: Show what you have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by keeping a reference to the last `QLineEdit` selected. Initialize `self.current_line_edit` to your first `QLineEdit`, then connect the `editingFinished` signal of each `QLineEdit` to your custom slot.

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    ...
    ...
    self.current_line_edit = self.line_edit_1
    self.tablewidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.onDoubleClick)
    self.line_edit_1.editingFinished.connect(self.onChangeLineEdit)
    self.line_edit_2.editingFinished.connect(self.onChangeLineEdit)
    self.line_edit_3.editingFinished.connect(self.onChangeLineEdit)
    ...
    ...

def onChange(self):
    self.current_line_edit = self.sender()

def onDoubleClick(self, item):
    self.current_line_edit.setText(item.text())
```